# Convert string to decimal and calculate, in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am new to shell scripting. My input file looks like below:

```
1.54
3.235
.7
```

I read this file, as each line into one variable.

```
ONE=`sed -n '1p' file`;
TWO=`sed -n '2p' file`;
THREE=`sed -n '3p' file`;
```

Now, I need to do some calculations ( like multiplication, division..) on these variables.
Anyone please advise.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the variables? As you use the same command to populate them, they should all contain the same value.

Comment: What shell do you use? Some shells don't support floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @choroba, It was a typo, I corrected it now.

Comment: I am using bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` does not supporting floating point arithmetic (only integer arithmetic). You need to pass the operations to a tool like `bc`.

For example:

```
DIV=$(echo "scale=3; $ONE/$TWO" | bc)
echo $DIV

MUL=$(echo "scale=3; $ONE/$DIV" | bc)
echo $MUL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `bc`. For example `echo "$ONE + $TWO + $THREE" | bc` give the sum of these numbers.

Comment: I tried this, it is working only for echoing. Why can't I take the result into another variable and do some more calculations ?

Comment: `someOtheRVariable=$(echo "$ONE + $TWO + $THREE" | bc)`  then `echo "$someOtheRVariable"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read complete file in an array
mapfile -t arr < file

# do some calculations
n=$( echo "${arr[0]} + ${arr[1]} - ${arr[2]}" | bc -l)

# display resul
echo "$n"

# output
# 4.075
```

Answer (score 0):

"awk" command is a useful alternative for converting and having operations on them.

Step 1: Put method with awk command upper of your codes.

```
calc(){ awk "BEGIN { print "$*" }"; }
```

Step 2: At your bash, you can call this method and having decimal operations simply.

```
FOUR=$(calc $ONE*$TWO/$THREE)
```

Note: If  you want to convert your string to decimal just, you can try this:

```
DECIMAL_ONE=$(calc $ONE*1)
```